# Multiple elements with different parents share the same width

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have bunch of inputs with labels declared like this:

```
<Form inline>
    <FormGroup>
        <ControlLabel>Label</ControlLabel>
        <FormControl />
    </FormGroup>
    <FormGroup>
        <ControlLabel>Another Label</ControlLabel>
        <FormControl />       
    </FormGroup>
    <FormGroup>
        <ControlLabel>Some very long label</ControlLabel>
        <FormControl />       
    </FormGroup>
</Form>
```

I would like to align them like this:
[image: wireframe drawing]

All labels to share the same width, but the width should be width of the widest element, which is unknown at design time.

Is it possible to do it in CSS in latest browsers? If no, any react component to help?

Comment: I can't see your image (blocked at my current location) but it's undoubtedly possible. One likely candidate is CSS flexbox, another is CSS grids, but grids won't likely be 'live' in major browsers (e.g. when it comes out from behind a browser prefix) until Q1 or Q2 2017.

Comment: Based on the structure...no. CSS has no method of equalising widths of elements that do not share a parent.

Comment: I failed miserably at meeting your spec: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/WGdpjy As @Paulie_D pointed out - you can't achieve this in pure CSS.